# Hide/Show Div on button click not working. Tried everything I know

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to programming and I'm learning on the go. So far I'v been able to work through all problems but I can't seem to crack the code on making a Div slide in and out of the page when a button is clicked. I'v tried all the solutions I could find including but still can't solve this.

Please see my code below:

```js
(function($) {
  $(".a").click(function() {
    $(".architecture").show('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 800);
  });
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $('.closea').click(function() {
    $('.architecture').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 800);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.architecture {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 44%;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<button class="content" class="a">Architecture</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

To have a strong idea of what I'm trying to achieve, please visit 'wetransfer.com', >Take me to free> and use the 'help' button toggle.

I know it's not ideal but I included the jQuery in the html file because Brackets showed me an error each time I tried to use the .js file. If anyone knows how to correct this please let me know as well. I'v heard that putting jQuery into the html is a bad habit.

Thanks in advance for any help. Cheers!

Comment: "putting jQuery into the html is a bad habit": more generally, mixing markup, presentation and logic is a bad habit

Comment: Where is the `.architecture` element? Also note that you have provided two `class` attributes on the button element, the second of which will be ignored.

Comment: Please use the `edit` button on your question. Code in comments is almost unreadable

Comment: And thanks for your quick response  guys

Comment: <div class="architecture">  
           <object class="archsvg" type="image/svg+xml" data="architecture-    icon.svg" width="260px" height="288.14px">  
         </object>    
        <a href="architecture.html">  
             <div class="arch">   
                <p class="to-architecture">Continue to 9haus Architecture</p>  
                <hr class="aline"/>  
            </div>  
           </a>  
          <button class="closea">x</button>  
         </div>

Comment: Sorry @RoryMcCrossan I'm just trying to figure out how the edit works.

Comment: @Chidz you press the "edit" button under your question.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Kaddath 's code solved the issue. Thank again everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had many things wrong here:

- `visibility: hidden;` is not impacted by show and hide, as far as i know, so the div will stay hidden. you should remove it. Edit following comments: `display` is impacted by hide and show if you need.
- the classes for your buttons and selectors were wrong, by the way, don't give hide and show to the same button as they will both trigger at the same time (not exactly, i let you try this)
- added the div with the good class "architecture" for the test

```js
(function($) {
  $(".a").click(function() {
    $(".architecture").show('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 800);
  });
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $('.b').click(function() {
    $('.architecture').hide('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 800);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.architecture {
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 44%;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button class="content a">show</button>
<button class="content b">hide</button>

<div class="architecture" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; border: 1px dotted red;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Good answer.  However I'd start with `display: none` in your `.architecture` css.

Comment: you're right, i'll add the precision to the notes too

Comment: Oh that worked. Thanks a lot. I'v also made the adjustments you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope This Will help you :)

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget that we're here to educate people, so please explain what the issue was, and how and why your code helps. Simply dumping code helps no one in the long run. Also note that W3Schools articles are often outdated (as can be seen in this example through their use of `on*` event attributes and `javascript:void(0)`) and some times just plain wrong. MDN is a far better and more accurate reference.